# Display multiple line graphs on a single plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I have some data (Change in historic Inflation data -monthly in USA) in a .csv file. I am able to plot the data in form of a line graph. I want to plot this data and also the cumulative data for the same in single plot in python. I am using the below code. But it plots as two plots one below other. Can someone help me with this.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""import the data from the provided input file ("us_infl.csv")"""
us_inf_data = pd.read_csv("us_infl.csv", header=0, names = ["","x"], index_col=0)
us_inf_data
"""Create an indexed time series from the dataset"""
us_inf_series = pd.Series(us_inf_data['x'].values, index = pd.date_range(start = '2003',periods = 180,freq = 'M'))
us_inf_series

"""plot the time series"""
plt.plot(us_inf_series, color = "black")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Delta Inflation Rate")
plt.title("Monthly change in US Inflation Rate")

cum_inf = np.cumsum(us_inf_data)
cum_inf.head()

us_inf_series.plot()
cum_inf.plot()
plt.title("Inflation Rate in USA Since 2003")
plt.xlabel("Time stamp")
plt.ylabel("Inflation rate")
plt.legend(["Delta Inflation Rate","Cumulative Inflation Rate"])
```

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then pass `ax=ax` when plotting each dataframe.